# Accessor properties and their function names

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, getter

All functions in ECMAScript 6 will have an appropriate value for their name property. And what about those names for the accessor properties (getters and setters)?

Example (from [Understanding ECMAScript 6](https://www.nostarch.com/ecmascript6) book):

```
var doSomething = function doSomethingElse() {
    // empty
};

var person = { 
    get firstName() {
        return "Nicholas"
    },
    sayName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

console.log(doSomething.name); // "doSomethingElse"
console.log(person.sayName.name); // "sayName"
console.log(person.firstName.name); // undefined, instead of "get firstName"
```

Can you explain why `person.firstName.name` returns `undefined`?

Comment: I don't believe there is a `name` property for getters and setters like other [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). Maybe a design goal? Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `person.firstName` is a getter, the return value is whatever the getter returns (`"Nicholas"` in your example), not the getter function itself, so you cannot access its name that way.

In order to get a reference to the function, you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

```js
var person = { 
    get firstName() {
        return "Nicholas"
    },
}

var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person, 'firstName');

console.log(descriptor);
console.log(descriptor.get.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `person.firstName === "Nicholas"` and `"Nicholas".name` does not exist.

When using a `getter`, your accessing to the actual returned value directly, you're not calling a function as far as the line that executes it understands, it's the same as attempting:

```
var obj = { something: 'someValue' };
console.log(obj.something.name);
```

Which will return undefined as well.

Comment: I believe he's asking why the `name` property of the `get` function doesn't return the `get`ter's name. All functions have a `name` property that can access the function's name.

Comment: @KeithA Indeed. I believe I answered properly. If you try to access the getter, you will not obtain a function by itself, you'll get the property it returns, so `typeof person.firstName === 'string'`, therefore one doesn't have the property `name` because it's not a function what we're handling.

Answer (score 1):

because `person.firstName` is the type of the return value, so `string`, and string has not a property `.name`

`person.sayname` and `doSomethingElse` are functions and have `.name` property

```
console.log(typeof doSomething); // function
console.log(typeof person.sayName); // function
console.log(typeof person.firstName); // string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the property `name` is only for **functions** or **classes**, not for *variables*.

If you have the code:

```
let var1 = "non function";
let var2 = {};
let var3 = function(){};
let var4 = function hello(){};
let var5 = class AClass{};

console.log(var1.name); // undefined
console.log(var2.name); // undefined
console.log(var3.name); // var3
console.log(var4.name); // hello
console.log(var5.name); // AClass
```

You can see the `var1` and `var2` aren't functions or classes and the others they are and have the property `name`.

Comment: You are conflating two things here. Variables are *containers for values* and functions and classes are *values*. Therefore functions can be assigned to variables. You are right that only functions have a `name` property. But what you are demonstrating is that *objects* and *strings* don't have a `name` property. Variables don't have properties anyway.